# Is " advertise" ok in this case?

Tags: tense, past-continuous

The first time I heard about you was on his blog . At this time he **was advertising** for a concert promoting the new release of your record.

I dont know if my verb to advertise is ok in this case and if it would be better to write advertised .

I think continuous is better because it was at this time when I went on his blog he was advertising.

Comment: I think the only problem here is the word **for**. Just remove it. "he was advertising a concert."

Comment: *At **that** time he was advertising a concert **to promote** the release of your record.* The words ***for*** and ***new*** are clumsy and unnecessary (but if ***new*** means ***recent***, that word can reasonably be used here).

Comment: Side note: The question should be: Is "advertise" ..., not Are "advertise" ... "Advertise" is just one word, so the verb should be singular. If you were asking about two words, then the verb should be plural. Like: Are "advertise" and "market" appropriate ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

to *advertise **for*** something is what you do when you are trying to get/obtain/find that something. So *advertising for a concert* doesn't make much sense (since "trying to obtain a concert" is rather unlikely)

But *advertising a concert* is fine. So *At this time he was advertising a concert* is good.